# how to become a network engineer

Tags: networking

I am 18 years old. I wish to become a network engineer. I don't know where I should start and what to study.  I am interested in learning through the internet.

Can any one please suggest any URLs and topics/subject to be covered by a person new to networking.

is it right for a fresher to start with CCNA certification directly

Thanks!

Comment: Server Fault has a lot more networking information you might find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you know about networks as is? What have you read on Wikipedia on the subject?

Why does this seem like a fake question?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite

Those are all fundamentals to networking. I would say make sure you understand those topics, and follow any WP links you don't know. You can use tools like VirtualBox to create a local virtual machine network to play with.

Comment: sir i actually want to get suggestions for experts that is why i posted this question in this site sir

Comment: well the fact that you stayed with the question for more than a few minutes leads me to believe you're serious I suppose. But I would say you'ld probably do better on ServerFault as @samoz pointed out. I'll add a few links to my answer.

Comment: shall i start with preparing for CCNA certification ?
is tat advisable for a fresher?

Comment: No. Start with reading on the topic. Start with building a small network for yourself for testing. Start with understanding what a network is. Then worry about advancing towards a ceritfication. If you wanted to get a CCNA then you should have asked "what is the best way to get a CCNA with no background?".

Comment: thanks a lot sir
i will cover the basic topics u suggest and then i will prepare for my certification.thanks a lot.